# What is the possible causes for a power supply to drop to zero once connected to a load (PCB)?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I have 2 identical PCBs. One of the boards causes the power supply to drop from 14V to 0V when connected. What are the possible issues? If you have face the similar situation before, do you mind sharing the solution you found?

Right now I am checking for connections with a multimeter. The board consists of a step down circuit. I think there may be issues with it.

Comment: It sounds like you have a short circuit on your PCB, or nearly so.

Comment: Diode backwards.

Comment: Current limit too low on power supply.

Comment: Short (solder or  something internal in a chip). Backwards chip can do this. Short under a chip with a thermal pad. Manufacturing issue with PCB (eg. short from copper pour to pad). The last one shouldn't happen if you paid for 100% probing of the bare PCB.

Comment: @TimWescott Damn, i got approx hundreds of pin to check if thats the case hahaha. Gonna spend days with this.

Comment: Please post your own answer or accept one of the existing ones instead of editing the answer into your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is likely a low resistant short on the board. This could be happening in one of the components, there could be a solder bridge between two pins or it could be happening interally the PCB itself.

First go for the low hanging fruit, inspect the PCB components to see if there are any direct shorts between pins. SMT components with pins on the bottom of the package could also be shorted.

Another thing about shorts is they dissipate a lot of heat, the easiest thing to do is to find somebody with the thermal camera and check out the board. Usually shorts are readily apparent because they dissipate the most power.

Another way to do this is maybe get a thermistor or just check it by hand and see if you can find a hot component (be careful).

If you can't do that then the last option is to pull components off one by one until you find the offending component. Another thing that you can do is just pull off voltage regulators or DC to DC converters until you find the rail that is shorted. Another thing that I've done in the past is cut power traces until I find the short.

I've only had one or two boards in years of manufacturing with internal shorts or issues with planes connecting in the PCB, while it's likely that this is not the problem don't rule it out

Comment: I do have similar case before which caused the component to heat up and i found out its due to a faulty component. However in this case, the components did not heat up, even after i let it run for a longer duration.

Answer (score 1):

One way to test the circuit is to apply some current, limited to no more than the normal operating voltage. You can follow the current flow with a multimeter on mV range. I've seen shorted bypass capacitors too.

Generally if the voltage is something like a diode drop it's a backward chip or other semiconductor in wrong. That part will tend to get hot enough to remove your fingerprint, at least temporarily. If it's less than a diode drop (say 50mV or 100mV) it's a dead short somewhere.

Comment: as i could not increase the voltage of the supply, i increased the current a little bit which allows me to increase the voltage slightly but still below 0V. Based on the checks done using a multimeter at mV, i found some pins to give a negative mV instead of a positive

Comment: If you probe from where it enters the board you'll see the mV increasing or decreasing (depending on polarity) along current paths (to or from the short). Branches that do not go to the short will have constant voltage on them. It's like climbing a mountain, you want to follow the paths that take  you uphill and ignore the ones that circle around.

Comment: Is it possible for the VCC and GND  pins of a switching voltage regulator to have a beep sound ? when i tested those pins using continuity test , it gave out a beep sound. I am guessing that the regulator short circuited internally.

Comment: @curiouser you have a good board and a bad board, right? If so, do you get the beep when you probe both boards, or only on the bad board? If it is a fault, anything connected from VCC to GND could be the problem. For example every capacitor from VCC to GND and every other chip powered by VCC is suspect. Just because you probed at the regulator doesn't mean the regulator is the faulty IC. But if the fault is definitely from VCC to GND, then at least you have a place to start looking.

Comment: @mkeith i tried to remove it to determine if the fault is at ic chip, but now 2 of the pins broke off and the ic chip still intact..

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to every single one of us at some point.

Since this is the first run of boards, here are some things to check.

1. Is a part backwards or rotated wrong somewhere? Could a diode be backwards and pulling down the power supply? It may help to trace the path of power in the schematic and look for parts which, if they were installed wrong, could cause this to happen.
2. Is there a copper-to-copper short on the bare PCB? If you have a bare PCB, can you apply power to it without the supply crashing? If not, at least you know it is related to a part. If so, you better debug the bare PCB before even looking at the boards with parts on them.
3. If you are stuck, one strategy is to just start removing parts from the board that may be causing the problem (anything connected to the input power rail). Maybe after you remove enough parts, the board will stop overloading the supply.
4. Another thing that can help is to use a thermal imaging camera. Keep the supply attached and see if anything is getting hot. If the supply is shutting down and not supplying current, find a beefier supply that will keep dumping current into the short circuit. Something will probably get hot. If you don't have the thermal imaging camera, watch for smoke. This is a destructive test.
5. If you are really, really stuck, start cutting the board in half and checking both halves for a short. Each time you cut it in half, the problem search area will get smaller. Eventually you will only have one really small area and you will hopefully find the problem.

If I think of any more techniques I will add them to the list. Don't give up. Perseverance is one element of engineering. If this stuff was easy, anyone could do it.

Comment: A solution you didn't mention, that may be useful: apply AC (or pulsing DC, if you want to avoid potentially turning on any diodes) to the power rails and use an H-field probe to trace out where the current's going. The proper calibrated ones are really expensive, but you can make a jury-rigged one out of a bit of coax with basic tools, and you don't need to know the absolute magnitude of the magnetic field for this, just where it's highest.

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause may be a capacitor short across the PCB +ve and -ve rails. A multimeter test across the rails would confirm that.

Next all the capacitors across the supply rails would have to be removed and checked to isolate the faulty one.